# Allow only one User-Agent, block the rest in nginx?

Tags: nginx

new to this site so i'll keep it brief:

I have currently:

```
    if ($http_user_agent ~* (A-certain-self-made-User-Agent-here)) {
            return 200;
    }
```

Which works very well. (Tested by switching 200 to 403).

**My question is**: Is there a way in: /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default to make it allow only **ONE** User-Agent and deny the rest?

I know this seems stupid, but it's something i'd like to have done, (if possible).
**Like maybe this?:**

```
    if (http_user_agent ~*(user-agent)) {
           return 200;
    else
           return 403;
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
if ($http_user_agent !~* (A-certain-self-made-User-Agent-here)) {
        return 403;
}
```

This should be a 'not match' on your certain user agent.   [Reference info here: HttpRewriteModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpRewriteModule#if)

Answer (score 4):

```
if ($http_user_agent !~* "A-certain-self-made-User-Agent-here") {
    return 403;
}
```

is working on my site.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following in the proper location

```
set $isallowed = "";
if ($http_user_agent = allowed_user_agent) {
    set $isallowed "${isallowed}YES";
}

if ($isallowed !~ YES) {
    rewrite ^ http://yourserver.com permanent;
}
```